# how to send a pdf file through http-post

Tags: pdf, http-post, httplistener

I need to send a PDF file through HTTP POST.

I'm sending it using a third party (nSoftware) dll.

But my question is, how to receive it at the server end and save it.

I tried it with HTTPlistener, but unable to do.

Can some one help me on this..

Thanks,
Maddy

Comment: So could you post what did you try, please?

Comment: Hi @Azat, Please find the code posted..

Answer (score 0):

I tried below..

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:122/");            
        listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

        listener.Start();
        this.listenThread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startlistener));
        listenThread1.Start();

    }
    private void startlistener(object s)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            ProcessRequest();

        }

    }
    private void ProcessRequest()
    {
        var result = listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var data_text = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream, context.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();
        var cleaned_data = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data_text);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];            
        int size = 1024 * 1024;
        context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, size);
        using (FileStream fsNew = new FileStream("E:\\temp\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fsNew.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";
        MessageBox.Show(cleaned_data);
        context.Response.Close();
    }
```

With this I'm able to save create a PDF but it's not opening, and also the data is something more than the actual in the original PDF (I think some headers of http).

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks,
Madhu